# Are Flow.js maps not writable?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

```
/* @flow */

let m: Map<number, string>;

m = new Map();

m[1] = 'qwe';
```

gives this errors:

```
7: m[1] = 'qwe';
   ^ Cannot assign `'qwe'` to `m[1]` because an index signature declaring the expected key / value type is not writable.
7: m[1] = 'qwe';
     ^ Cannot assign `'qwe'` to `m[1]` because number [1] is incompatible with `$SymbolToStringTag` [2].
References:
7: m[1] = 'qwe';
     ^ [1]
[LIB] ..//static/v0.111.0/flowlib/core.js:606:     +[key: $SymbolToStringTag]: any;
                                                          ^ [2]
```

you can try it here
https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVMCmAXMBbALjAFkBDABwB4A7AVzwCNMAnAGjAGdtmBLagcwB8AbnR4wAXjDVMSMuQAUASlGo8AbQCMAXUlgA5AEcEmfcKA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah damn it, that's because in JS with maps you are not allowed to `m[key] = value;` only `m.set(key, value)`.